# magento admin block not gets created

Tags: php, magento

I am working on a custom admin module. Here is my controller -

```
<?php

class Adept_Sellers_Adminhtml_SellersController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action
{
    protected function _initAction() {
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            ini_set("display_errors","1");

            $this->loadLayout()
                    ->_setActiveMenu('sellers/items')
                    ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Sellers Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Sellers Manager'));

            return $this;
    }

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->_initAction()
                        ->renderLayout();
    }

        public function viewsellerAction() {

            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            ini_set("display_errors","1");

            $this->loadLayout();

            $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('adept/adminhtml_sellers_edit'))
                 ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('adept/adminhtml_sellers_edit_tabs'));

            $this->renderLayout();

        }
```

Block files are -

```
Adept/Sellers/Block/Adminhtml/Sellers.php
```

and

```
<?php
class Adept_Sellers_Block_Adminhtml_Sellers extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->_removeButton('add');
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_sellers';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'sellers';
    $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('sellers')->__('Seller Request');


    parent::__construct();
    $this->_removeButton("add");
  }
}
```

Adept/Sellers/Block/Adminhtml/Sellers/Edit.php

code -

```
<?php

class Adept_Sellers_Block_Adminhtml_Sellers_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'sellers';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_sellers';

        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('sellers')->__('Send For Approval')); 
    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        if( Mage::registry('sellers_data') && Mage::registry('sellers_data')->getId() ) {
            return Mage::helper('sellers')->__("Edit Requests'%s'", $this->htmlEscape(Mage::registry('sellers_data')->getTitle()));
        } else {
            return Mage::helper('sellers')->__('New Order');
        }
    }
}
```

Adept/Sellers/Block/Adminhtml/Sellers/Edit/Form.php

code -

```
<?php

class Adept_Sellers_Block_Adminhtml_Sellers_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
  protected function _prepareForm()
  {
      $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
                                      'id' => 'edit_form',
                                      'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
                                      'method' => 'post',
                                      'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
                                   )
      );

      $form->setUseContainer(true);
      $this->setForm($form);
      return parent::_prepareForm();
  }
}
```

Adept/Sellers/Block/Adminhtml/Sellers/Edit/Tabs.php

code is -

```
<?php

class Adepts_Sellers_Adminhtml_Sellers_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs
{
  public function __construct()
  {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->setId('sellers_tabs');
      $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');

      $this->setTitle(Mage::helper('sellers')->__('Sellers Information'));
  }

  protected function _beforeToHtml()
  {
      $this->addTab('form_section', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('sellers')->__('Order Information'),
          'title'     => Mage::helper('sellers')->__('Order Information'),
          'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('sellers/adminhtml_sellers_edit_tab_form')->toHtml(),
          'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('sellers/adminhtml_sellers_edit_tab_form')->toHtml(),
      ));

      return parent::_beforeToHtml();
  }
}
```

Adept/Sellers/Block/Adminhtml/Sellers/Edit/Tab/Form.php

code is -

```
<?php

class Adept_Sellers_Block_Adminhtml_Sellers_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
  protected function _prepareForm()
  {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->setForm($form);
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('seller_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('sellers')->__('Seller information')));

        $fieldset->addField('firstname', 'label', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('sellers')->__('First Name'),
            'name'      => 'firstname',
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('lastname', 'label', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('sellers')->__('Last Name'),
            'name'      => 'lastname',
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('email', 'label', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('sellers')->__('Email'),
            'name'      => 'email',
        )); 

        if ($customer = Mage::registry('current_customer')) {
            $form->setValues($customer->getData());
        }

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

when I try to edit from the grid, it calls the controller `viewsellerAction()` with a blank page (having only header and footer). It does not showing any error. I am not getting understand what would be the error or am I missing something?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call your block by 'adept/adminhtml_sellers_edit'

Your block class is class Adept_Sellers_Block_Adminhtml_Sellers

Adept is your company... Sellers is your module

Call block by: 'sellers/adminhtml_sellers_edit'

It's work if sellers is the key for your module into your config module

Comment: ohh.. what a silly mistake it is.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Activate error reporting from your magento index.php file. And activate logs... It's better to see errors ;)